# Firebase Cloud Messaging FCM Send Notification Message Android

Tags: android, firebase, notifications, firebase-cloud-messaging

I have two apps that use FCM, Client and Worker app. ***Client*** is sending the message:

```
String jsonLatLng = new Gson().toJson(new LatLng(Common.placeLatLng.latitude, Common.placeLatLng.longitude));
String clientToken = FirebaseInstanceId.getInstance().getToken();
Notification notification = new Notification(clientToken, jsonLatLng);
Sender content = new Sender(tokenId, notification);

mFCMService.sendMessage(content)
        .enqueue(new Callback<FCMResponse>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(Call<FCMResponse> call, Response<FCMResponse> response) {
                if(response.body().success == 1) {
                    Toast.makeText(HomeActivity.this, "Request sent.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                } else {
                    Toast.makeText(HomeActivity.this, "Request not sent.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(Call<FCMResponse> call, Throwable t) {

            }
});
```

Wherein **Notification.java** is

```
public class Notification {
    public String title;
    public String body;
    ...
}
```

**Sender.java** is

```
public class Sender {
    public String to;
    public Notification notification;
    ...
}
```

And with the ***Worker*** app, it receives:

```
public class MyFirebaseMessaging extends FirebaseMessagingService {
    @Override
    public void onMessageReceived(RemoteMessage remoteMessage) {
        //Convert lat lng
        LatLng clientLocation = new Gson().fromJson(remoteMessage.getNotification().getBody(), LatLng.class);

        Intent intent = new Intent(getBaseContext(), NotificationActivity.class);
        intent.putExtra("lat", clientLocation.latitude);
        intent.putExtra("lng", clientLocation.longitude);
        intent.putExtra("client", remoteMessage.getNotification().getTitle());

        intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
        startActivity(intent);
    }
}
```

These codes work perfectly fine, however, I need to add more details, specifically, I want to send data from 2 String variables, *serviceFee* & *serviceType* over to the Worker app. I tried modifying the body of the Notification wherein I created a class called *Body* with three variables (jsonLatLng, serviceFee, serviceType), but I can't figure out how the worker will be able to get the data of Body or if that's even possible. Please help. Thank you! :)